# Calculating Hash Collisions with 160 bits

Tags: hash, cryptography, collision, hash-function, hash-collision

Assume a hash function that produces digests of 160 bits. How many messages do we need to hash to get a collision with approximately 75% probability?

Thank you for you help :)

Comment: Too many. Every computer on earth, working at full capacity until the heat death of the universe type of scale.

Comment: @mypetlion Or two specific ones, for SHA-1 :P

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't involve programming or program development.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is that there's a 50% chance of a collision after `sqrt(n)` numbers are drawn. The number is slightly more than that, but the square root is a good guideline. So in your case you have a 50% chance of collision after 2^80 tries.

The other rule of thumb is that after `4*sqrt(n)`, your probability of getting a duplicate is nearly a certainty.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_of_a_shared_birthday_(collision), you can compute the number, `n` of values you need to draw to get a probability `p` of a duplicate by:

```
n = sqrt(2 * d * ln(1/(1-p)))
```

Where `ln` is the natural logarithm, and `p` is the probability from 0 to 1.0.

So in your case:

```
n = sqrt(2 * 2^160 * ln(1/.25))
n = sqrt(2^161 * 1.38629)
```

Which is something less than 2^81.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the range of `2 septillion`. That's 2,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 messages. Here's the equation.

```
chance of collision = 1 - e^(-n^2 / (2 * d))
```

Where `n` is the number of messages, `d` is the number of possibilities. So if `d` is `2^160`, then `n` is going to be in the neighbourhood of `2^80.7`.

Comment: I.e. about half of the hash output size size due to the birthday "paradox". Note that the memory requirements to store the hashes to compare them with each other will be in the same order, and as far as I know there is not enough memory *in the world* to do such a thing. These hashes have been created to avoid collisions. SHA-1 however fails at this, google "sha-1 shattered".

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Not half the output size, but rather the square root of the output size.